# Windows Authentication not working on root site of an IIS 8.5 based web site

Tags: iis, authentication, iis-8.5, asp.net-mvc

I have a intranet web site that is using Windows Authentication. When it is the root web application of the site I get a 403.14 error. When I have a sub-application on the same server Windows authentication works correctly for those apps.
All sites are accessible only via HTTPS.
We are using an internally generated SSL certificate from our internal certificate authority.

Looking at the logs I see that my Windows AD information is being passed in the GET.

The site is built on ASP.Net MVC. I have verified that the appPool is configured correctly. i.e. Integrated Pipeline & .Net4

Any ideas what is causing this? Why can I access my sub apps properly but not the root?

What can I do to get this working as expected?

My Fiddler capture shows:

```
200 HTTP Tunnel to mysite:443
401 HTTPS mysite /
403 HTTPS mysite /
```

Comment: My Fiddler capture shows:
200 HTTP Tunnel to mysite:443
401 HTTPS mysite /
403 HTTPS mysite /

Comment: Windows Authentication has nothing to do with https, it works fine in http which may make it easier to diagnose what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

403.14 error occurs when you dont have a default document (start page of the application) added in IIS.

Follow Method 2 in this - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942062/http-error-403-14-forbidden-error-when-you-open-an-iis-7-0-webpage